# Empty angle brackets in C++

Tags: c++, rxcpp

When exploring RxCpp library I encountered the following sample which I cannot interpret.

```
    auto ints = rxcpp::observable<>::create(
        [](rxcpp::subscriber<int> s){
            s.on_next(1);
            s.on_next(2);
            s.on_completed();
    });
```

There are two declarations of `observable` class in the library:

```
template<class T, class SourceOperator>
class observable
    : public observable_base<T>
{
// ...
};

template<>
class observable<void, void>
{
// ...
};
```

What I was not able to comprehend is how the compiler manages to accept `rxcpp::observable<>.` piece. There could have been many explicit specializations of `observable` for different types, other than `void,void`.

The question is how the compiler interprets empty angle brackets in this code: `rxcpp::observable<>.`

I see no default template parameters in `observable` class, neither variadic template parameters which could explain this.

Then I thought it was somehow related to explicit template specialization, and tried to reproduce it in an isolated program, for instance like this

```
namespace isolated {
  template<class T>
  class Test {
  public:
    static void say() {
      cout << "I am generic" << endl;
    }
  };

  template<>
  class Test<int> {
  public:
    static void say() {
      cout << "I am integer" << endl;
    }
  };
}

int main() {
  isolated::Test<>::say(); // ERROR: too few arguments for class template.....
}
```

However it does not compile even though there is only one explicit specialization.

Comment: Looks like your missing something.  The only way `rxcpp::observable<>` can work is if there are default template arguments.  Look in the source code and see if there is a forward declaration of `observable` like `template<class T = something, class SourceOperator = something_else>
class observable`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah He's talking about at the calling site (snippet 1), not the specialization in snippet 2.

Comment: look for a declaration of the class template. It can have default template arguments. E.g. `template<class T = void, class SourceOperator = void>
class observable;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are missing is

```
template<
     class T = void,
     class SourceObservable = typename std::conditional<std::is_same<T, void>::value,
         void, dynamic_observable<T>>::type>
 class observable;
```

from lines 142-146 of [rx-predef.hpp](http://reactivex.io/RxCpp/rx-predef_8hpp_source.html)

This forward declaration supplies default template arguments for the `observable` class and allows you to write `observable<>` which will use those default values.  In your example that would be accomplished by adding

```
template<class T = int>
class Test;
```

Which gives you

```
namespace isolated {
  template<class T = int>
  class Test;

  template<class T>
  class Test {
  public:
    static void say() {
      cout << "I am generic" << endl;
    }
  };

  template<>
  class Test<int> {
  public:
    static void say() {
      cout << "I am integer" << endl;
    }
  };
}

int main() {
  isolated::Test<>::say(); // ERROR: too few arguments for class template.....
}
```

and outputs

```
I am integer
```

in this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bed3add80c3f0f7c)

Comment: I wonder why someone would want to place forward declarations with template parameter defaults in a separate header, which is not supposed to be included directly by the library user.

Comment: @Mooh There seems to be quite a bit of dependency between the header files.  Most likely that was the spot they "had to use" with their design in order for the defaults to get pulled into everywhere correctly.